# Laravel : how to show CategoryTitle in show views from pivot table

Tags: laravel, relation

I want show category_title in post views.i'm using pivot for category_id and post_id

Post Model:

```
public function categories()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_post','post_id','category_id');
}
```

Show.blade.php

```
{{$post->categories->category_title}}
```

but show me this error

> Property [category_title] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access it directly, with `belongsToMany` you're getting multiple objects.

To access this you need to follow it as below.

```
@foreach($post->categories as $category)
{{ $category->category_title }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can access it as below.

```
{{ $post->categories->pluck('category_title ')->implode(',') }}
```